# R: Using dplyr to Mutate Multiple Columns

Tags: r, dplyr

There are various questions on Stack Overflow regarding this, but I have been unable to find a solution to my question, which follows.

Suppose I have a data frame (or tibble) `df` with two columns, say `X1` and `X2`. I have  a function, say `f`, which takes inputs `X1` and `X2` and outputs a *vector*, say `[V1, V2]`.
Now, if the output were a singleton, then I would be able to write

```
df %>% mutate(V = f(X1,X2))
```

to add a column labelled `V` to my `df`, and the entry would be `f(X1,X2)`. However, I want to add *two* columns, `V1` and `V2`. I do not know how to do this.

Of course, I could do something like

```
df %>% mutate(V1 = f(X1,X2)[1], V2 = f(X1,X2)[2]),
```

but this (I assume) involves calling the function `f` twice; I have a large data set, and would rather not call it twice.
Alternatively, I could do

```
df %>% mutate(V_list = as.list(f(X1,X2)), V1 = V_list[[1]], V2 = V_list[[2]]) %>% select(-V_list),
```

but this seems like a rather clunky way, and I'd rather not.

Further, I would like eventually to apply this to a `group`ed tibble, and so then the naive way of writing this would duplicate `V_list` for each entry in the group. As such, ideally any answer would be 'vectorisable', in the following sense.
Suppose I have done `df %>% group_by(var1)` and have a function `f` which takes a data frame with two columns as its input -- this should be thought of as 'a vector of pairs' -- and then outputs a new data frame with two columns.

---

Here is some code to set-up the example.

```
library(dplyr)
df = tibble(var1 = c(1,1,2,2), X1 = c(1,2,3,4), X2 = c(5,6,7,8))
f = function(sub_df, var){ return( data.frame(x1 = (x1+x2)^var, x2 = (x1-x2)^var) ) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function outputs a data.frame it will be auto-spliced into new columns by mutate

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df = tibble(var1 = c(1,1,2,2), X1 = c(1,2,3,4), X2 = c(5,6,7,8))

f = function(x1,x2) tibble(a = x1 + x2, b = x1 - x2)

df %>%
  mutate(f(X1, X2))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>    var1    X1    X2     a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     5     6    -4
#> 2     1     2     6     8    -4
#> 3     2     3     7    10    -4
#> 4     2     4     8    12    -4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or if your function outputs a vector you can use `purrr:map2` with `tidyr::unnest_wider`

Modify function so output is named

```
f = function(x1,x2) c(a = x1 + x2, b = x1 - x2)
```

Create a new column which is a list containing a vector for each row, then apply `unnest_wider` to this column to split the vector elements into their own columns.

```
df %>%
  mutate(new = map2(X1, X2, f)) %>%
  unnest_wider(new)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#    var1    X1    X2     a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     5     6    -4
# 2     1     2     6     8    -4
# 3     2     3     7    10    -4
# 4     2     4     8    12    -4
```

Comment: Would this work for groups? For example, instead of the function `f` above, maybe I want to `group_by(var1)` then fit a `lm` to the data from `X1` and `X2` (say `X1 ~ X2`); from this, I want to extra the two coefficients. This means I'd end up with a data frame with two rows and three columns: `var1`, `coeff1` and `coeff2`

Comment: Yes. unnest_wider just splits a list column into separate columns, it works the same if the list column was created after grouping, or if it was created with summarise rather than mutate (as it would be in the example you give of a lm for each group), it's unrelated to how the list column was created.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an ideal solution but I have faced this situation and this is what I usually do. Return a delimiter separated string from the function and `separate` the column based on that delimiter.

```
f = function(x1,x2){ return( toString(c(x1+x2, x1-x2))) }

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(new = map2_chr(X1, X2, f)) %>%
  separate(new, c("col1", "col2"), sep = ",", convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     X1    X2  col1  col2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     3     4    -2
#2     2     4     6    -2
```

Comment: This is a little unsatisfying, but if I cannot find a nicer method, it does look like this should work, thanks! +1 -- I'm not sure how I'd vectorise this, though, to make it work for groups...